# Script to Create Custom XML Entries for x-wallpapers.xml

Tags: scripts, files, desktop-background, xml

I know there is a way to do this, but I just dumped a bunch of my favorite wallpaper files in /usr/share/backgrouds/.  In order for my Ubutnu 17.10 to use them, I need to edit the artful-wallpapers.xml file and add each file name to a statement looking like this:

```
<wallpaper>
 <name>calm</name>
 <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/02488_calm_1440x900.jpg</filename>
 <options>zoom</options>
 <pcolor>#000000</pcolor>
 <scolor>#000000</scolor>
 <shade_type>solid</shade_type>
</wallpaper>
```

This is long and tedious to do one at a time, and I am sure I have merged data before, but for the life of me I cannot remember how.

A script would be very helpful, or at least directions to a tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Rod

Answer (score 3):

**XML Format Filenames in Folder via Bash Script**

You can accomplish this easily with a bash script. This will output all the xml you need so you can copy/paste it into artful-wallpapers.xml.

This script will take all filenames in current folder and format it into the XML from your question. You can easily modify it to fit your needs.

**The BASH Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
arr=(*)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
if [ "$i" != "makeXML" -a ! -d "$i" ]
then
   echo "<wallpaper>
 <name>$i</name>
 <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/$i</filename>
 <options>zoom</options>
 <pcolor>#000000</pcolor>
 <scolor>#000000</scolor>
 <shade_type>solid</shade_type>
</wallpaper>
"
fi
done
```

**How to use it**

Create a folder in your home folder called 'wallpapers' and put all the images you want to use in this folder.

Place above script in a plain-text file called makeXML inside the folder with your photos (~/wallpapers). Run from the terminal:

```
$ cd ~/wallpapers
$ bash makeXML
```

Paste the output on the screen into your x-wallpapers.xml file inside the wallpapers tag.

Finally move all the images from ~/wallpapers to /usr/share/backgrounds and delete the wallpapers folder.

Comment: Joshua:  Thanks so much.  I just ran it and so far it looks good, now to try it out and see if it changes the wallpapers.

I will be saving that little bit of script I can see how using parts of it could make my life much easier.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Excellent Script!!!