# Wallpaper / background folder in 20.04

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I need to deploy some company backgrounds to several desktops and laptops running Ubuntu 20.04.
I want to do this via a script, and not via each user manually adding one-by-one.

Adding to `/usr/share/backgrounds` has no effect.
I've seen references to `~/.cache/gnome-control-center/backgrounds`
on gnome forums but not in user folders on Ubuntu.

BTW - Adding below `~/Pictures` has been rejected by users, so I need to do it properly in the OS.

Where on the system do I place the files?

Comment: you need to create xml file after keeping your pics in `/usr/share/backgrounds`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1032855/739431

Comment: `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/` the xml file inside this directory holds which one to show in settings background section..

Comment: Thanks Pratap. Presumably that script needs to run after every addition of a new picture?

Comment: yes.. other wise you need to manually edit the file..

Comment: If you browse AskUbuntu you will get more sripts.. which automates the process once you add any pics to that folder.. and updates while logging out or reboot etc..